# Using javascript to control div visibility style

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

Hi I have this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function on_off(div)
    {
        var divbox = document.getElementByID(div);

        if(divbox.style.visibility == 'hidden')
            divbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
        else
            divbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is using a link and when the event of clicking the link happens a script runs that toggles the visibility of a div. Here is the link code:

```
 <li><a onclick="on_off('postArticle')" href='#'>Post Article</a></li>
```

and the div that I want to toggle the visibility of:

```
<div id="postArticle">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="contentbox1">
            <div id="articleHEADER">
                    <h2>Post an Article</h2>    
            </div>
            <p>Title</p>
            <input type="text" name="Title" size="40">
            <br>
            <p>Content</p>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
            </textarea>


            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#postArticle
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

For some reason it is not working. The div visibility is off and when I click the link it is not becoming visible.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: `display` and `visibility` are two different CSS properties. `display` doesn't have `visible` value, while `visibility` has. Don't mix them up.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to edit the JS code and left it like that when I posted it on here. I still not working when I replace it with visibility

Comment: @user3703944 post a JSFiddle

Comment: @Infer-On http://jsfiddle.net/C4Tvn/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function on_off(div)
{
    var divbox = document.getElementById(div); //Id, not ID

    if(divbox.style.visibility == 'hidden')
        divbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
    else
        divbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';


}
```

Comment: Sorry for the hassle man but I'm a poor javascript user. Thanks that solved my problem!

Comment: @nicael mmmh there is a bug, this work only after first click ;)

Comment: @Infer-On dumb question: why "there is a bug"?

Comment: because the visibility hidden are set by css, so your solution work only at the second click

Comment: @nicael already tested and it is bugged, but np you've solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to sintax problems, there is a problem with your script; you test `style` property of your target element, but you set the `style` via `css`, so you set `visibility` to hidden at the first click, so there is a **BUG**, instead you have to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/C4Tvn/5/)

**JavaScript**

```
function on_off(div)
        {
            var divbox = document.getElementById(div);

            if(divbox.style.visibility == 'hidden')
                divbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
            else
                divbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
```

**CSS**

```
#postArticle
{
    //visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="adminmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="on_off('postArticle')" href='#'>Post Article</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Edit Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>View Logs</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>View Comments</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="postArticle" style="visibility: hidden">
            <div class="content">
                <article class="contentbox1">
                <div id="articleHEADER">
                        <h2>Post an Article</h2>    
                </div>
                <p>Title</p>
                <input type="text" name="Title" size="40">
                <br>
                <p>Content</p>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
                </textarea>


                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Infer-On that eliminated the bug